# Which object was the chosen option from ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, contextmenustrip

I make windows form application. I have on form TreeView, I add few nodes and add ContextMenuStrip.

```
  var menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
  menu.Items.Add("Some text", new Bitmap(1, 1), new EventHandler(function_name));

  var treeView = new TreeView(..);
  treeView.ContextMenuStrip = menu;      

  treeView.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode()
  {
         ...
         Tag = someObject
  });
```

My problems is how can I check in function `function_name` on which treeNode was clicked and chosen option from ContextMenuStrip

## edit

function_name sygnature

```
 public void pokaz_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the TreeNodeMouseClick event. In your TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler you will have access to a `TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs` argument. This argument contains a number of properties you can use to check which mouse button was clicked on which node. For example.

```
private TreeNode rightClickeNode;

void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        rightClickedNode = e.Node;
    }
}
```

You can then access rightClickedNode from your `function_name`.

Answer (score 1):

what is the signature of the `function_name` method?

generally you can check the content of the sender parameter but it could happen it is the `TreeView` and not the `TreeNode`, if so you can check the properties of the `e` parameter.

Another way is that at every mouse down you make sure you select the node under the mouse in the TreeView so when `function_name` executes you get your node taking `treeview.SelectedNode`

Comment: How can I select node on event mouseDown? If I can do it, then in function_name I will be check which node is selected

Comment: again checking content of the e parameter in the OnMouseDown event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the node selected right before the Context Menu is shown and then you just need to check the `SelectedNode` property.  Something like this:

```
private void treeView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //See what node is at the location that was just clicked
    var clickedNode = treeView.GetNodeAt(e.Location);

    //Make that node the selected node
    treeView.SelectedNode = clickedNode;
}

private void function_name(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentNode = treeView.SelectedNode;

    //Do something with currentNode
}
```